# Excel 2013 power query - SQL query with a dynamic parameter

Tags: sql, dynamic, parameters, where-clause, powerquery

however I have looked from the web I cant find a simple(!) example that would show how to use and have a SQL query that would use in the WHERE a dynamic parameter value.

What I'm looking for is that the end user would be able to change a value in the column in the spreadsheet (ParameterTable?) and refresh the data using this new value as a parameter.

Perhaps an example describes best what I'm after.

I would have a table in excel that would have two columns, named ParameterName and ParameterValue. These would then have values PARM1 and 1
(Sorry but appears that I cant post an image here)

The the query could be like this, so if 1=1 retrieve the current date
(this  is oracle but should be the same for most other databases)

SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 1;

How should I change the above so that it would use the ParamaterName and ParameterValue, i.e. that the rightmost "1" could be changed dynamically to any value. If the value would be anything else than "1" no results would be returned.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I have another way to pass parameter into Power Query. I make sure it works.

Step 1: Create a table named "Infodesk" in excel, or you can name it as you wish. My table "Infodesk" contains column "Script" where I place the SQL script in this column.

Step 2: Create a blank Power Query, click on Advance Editor, and input following code

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("192.168.23.81", "dbo.name", [Query= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Infodesk"]}[Content][Script]{0}])

in
    Source
```

And then, run your query. The code [Script]{0}] will get data from 1st row, you can place multiple script in the column, then change {0} >> {1} or {2} ... to get data from other rows.

In order to change any parameter in SQL script, you may use the excel function =CONCATENATE() to combine multiple excel cells into a completed SQL.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked for me in Excel Office 365, the only modification was to remove the semi-colon from the end of the OPs query. It is critical that, once you have the "Power Query Editor" window open, you click "Home" and then "Advanced Editor" - this opens a window where the "let ... in Source" code should be pasted. So in my case, this was the value for the first row in the "Script" column:
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 1

Also Note: if you modify the excel table table_names, column_name, it's location sheet_name etc. the Power Query Code will not automatically update.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who possibly needs:

Create on any sheet a table holding your parameters, say, `tParam`.
Assign a variable:

`tParam = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tParam"]}[Content]`

Then join it to your database table if you use AND logic:

`tResult = Table.Join(tDatabaseSrc, {"Col1", "Col2"}, tParam, {"ColParameter1", "ColParameter2"}, JoinKind.Inner)`

This trick won't work if you need OR logic on anything more complex than just ANDs. Then use

`tResult = Table.SelectRows(tDatabase, each [Col1] = tParam{0}[ColParameter1] or [Col2] = tParam{0}[ColParameter2])`

You can use even more complex conditions, but you need to prepare some data first. For example, rather than using

`each [Col1] = tParam{0}[ColParameter1] or [Col1] = tParam{0}[ColParameter2]) [.....] or [Col1] = tParam{0}[ColParameter10])`

you can use just

`Table.SelectRows(tDatabaseSrc, each List.Contains(ListOfParameters, [Col1]))`

Set this `ListOfParameters` variable in some previous step(s).

In case you use Native Query (what is not the Best Practice, indeed), then maybe you will lose Query Folding. On the other hand, you can load every parameter in a single variable:

`tParam = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tParam"]}[Content],
tParam1 = tParam{0}[ColParameter1],
tParam2 = tParam{0}[ColParameter2],
etc etc`

, and then just insert them in your query. Again, this is not good, as it is subject to SQL Injection attack, but will do as a fast and non-permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using filters in this scenario. Your queries would look something like this:

Query ParameterValue:

```
let
    // This can be created by using From Table and then drilling into a cell
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]{0}[ParameterValue]
in
    Source
```

Query ParameterName:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]{0}[ParameterName]
in
    Source
```

Query that uses the filter:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server", "database"),
    DatabaseTableStepName = Source{[Schema="SchemaName",Item="ItemName"]}[Data],
    Custom1 = Table.SelectRows(DatabaseTableStepName, each Record.Field(_, ParameterName) = ParameterValue)
in
    Custom1
```

This uses SQL Server, but it should look similar for Oracle (some of the initial navigation steps will be different).

The last query can also be created by adding a step like this to formula bar once you've chosen the table you want to filter on:

```
= Table.SelectRows(DatabaseTableStepName, each Record.Field(_, ParameterName) = ParameterValue)
```

Another way you could do it is to use the Native Query feature, and build the strings dynamically using the & operator. I recommend avoiding this approach if possible because you will get prompted each time you change the parameter and because Power Query will not escape the strings for you if you build the strings dynamically (so you are vulnerable to SQL injection).

Answer (score 1):

Remarked way with *Native Query and &* was not straight clear for me, so I'd better left here working example

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("serverName", "dbName", [Query="select CurrencyCode from tCurrList where CurrencyCode = " & Number.ToText( Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CCode"]}[Content]{0}[CCode] )])
in
    Source
```

Comment: You can simplify conversion to text if you use `parameters` https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/12/11/passing-parameters-to-sql-queries-with-value-nativequery-in-power-query-and-power-bi/