# Dynamic Lookup Table in Excel Using Powerquery

Tags: sql, excel, dynamic, lookup, powerquery

I would like to use data in excel that is inputted by a stakeholder and use this as a lookup for sql queries that I am running.

For example the lookup table might look like this:
Column 1: Bundle Codes
Column 2: Product Codes (for all the items in each different bundle)

| Bundle Codes | Product Codes |
| --- | --- |
| A | 123 |
| A | 234 |
| B | 777 |
| B | 666 |

I want to be able to understand if people buy the products in column 2 after they have received a Bundle that contained those products.

At the moment the only thing I have succeeded in doing is turning the user inputs into an excel table. I'm stuck on how I get SQL to recognise this table. I'm thinking it would be good if I could load straight from excel into SQL as a temporary table? Is this possible?

Hope this makes sense, will elaborate if more detail would be useful

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322381

Comment: To use `NativeQuery` parameters, see: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/12/11/passing-parameters-to-sql-queries-with-value-nativequery-in-power-query-and-power-bi/